# GitHub Actions pass list of variables to shell script

Tags: yaml, github-actions

Using GitHub Actions, I would like to invoke a shell script with a list of directories.
(Essentially equivalent to passing an Ansible vars list to the shell script)

I don't really know how, is this even possible? Here's what I have until now, how could one improve this?

```yaml
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

    tags:
      - v*

  pull_request:

jobs:
  run-script:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Run script on targets
        run: ./.github/workflows/script.sh {{ targets }}
        env:
          targets:
            - FolderA/SubfolderA/
            - FolderB/SubfolderB/
```

Comment: I don't think you can set arrays in the environment. For what you show, you could just insert the strings directly in the `run:` field; where do you really get the targets from?

Comment: One option could be to use the [`join`](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#join) function with a blank, but that requires that your directory names don't contain blanks.

Comment: That's no problem, folders don't contain blanks. Would I be able to specify the path to the subfolders separately from the run ?

Comment: For a robust solution, you could use a separate step where you set the directories and then reference them in your "Run script on targets" step. The previous step could write to a temporary file, or set an output with a JSON object to then reference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I was able to do this with the following YAML (truncated):

```yaml
...
with:
  targets: |
    FolderA/SubfolderA
    FolderB/SubfolderB
```

The actual GitHub Action passes this as an argument like the following:

```yaml
runs:
  using: docker
  image: Dockerfile
  args:
    - "${{ inputs.targets }}"
```

What this does is simply sends the parameters as a string with the newline characters embedded, which can then be iterated over similar to an array in a POSIX-compliant manner via the following shell code:

```bash
#!/bin/sh -l

targets="${1}"

for target in $targets
do
  echo "Proof that this code works: $target"
done
```

Which should be capable of accomplishing your desired task, if I understand the question correctly. You can always run something like `sh ./script.sh $target` in the loop if your use case requires it.

Comment: Hi Aaron, do you have a successful run in i.e. a public shareable GitHub action so as I can verify and approve your answer?
The second option involving a loop doesn't address the problem fully, since 2 independent runs might run correctly but 2 dependent runs might not (depending on your core logic.)

Comment: @MihaiGalos sure! I just actually finished a GitHub Action repository today that depends on this logic, you can see a successful run of it here: https://github.com/meese-enterprises/meeseOS/runs/7266876868?check_suite_focus=true. Let me know if you can't see it!